# ModX: How to retrieve logged in web user's user group?

Tags: php, session-variables, modx, modx-revolution

I am using the Login addon (http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/Login) and am able to get some info about the user using:

`print_r($_SESSION);`

But I am wondering how to get that users user group (name or ID). Would anyone know how to go about this? Thanks!

PS: what `print_r($_SESSION);` give me:

```
Array
(
    [modx.user.0.resourceGroups] => Array
    (
        [web] => Array ( ) 
    ) 
    [modx.user.0.attributes]     => Array 
    (
        [web] => Array
        (
            [modAccessContext] => Array
            (
                [web] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                    (
                        [principal] => 0 
                        [authority] => 0 
                        [policy]    => Array ( [load] => 1 ) 
                     ) 
                  )
            ) 
            [modAccessResourceGroup]       => Array ( ) 
            [modAccessCategory]            => Array ( ) 
            [sources.modAccessMediaSource] => Array ( )
        )
    ) 
[modx.user.contextTokens] => Array ( [web] => 2 ) 
[modx.web.user.token]     => modx507e2d531fedb5.20134124_250c977bed72111.66166942 
[modx.web.session.cookie.lifetime] => 0
[modx.user.2.resourceGroups] => Array ( [web] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) ) 
[modx.user.2.attributes] => Array ( [web] => Array ( [modAccessContext] => Array ( [web] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [principal] => 2 [authority] => 9999 [policy] => Array ( [load] => 1 [list] => 1 [view] => 1 [save] => 1 [remove] => 1 [copy] => 1 [view_unpublished] => 1 ) ) ) ) 
[modAccessResourceGroup] => Array ( [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [principal] => 2 [authority] => 9999 [policy] => Array ( [load] => 1 [list] => 1 [view] => 1 ) ) ) ) 
[modAccessCategory] => Array ( ) [sources.modAccessMediaSource] => Array ( ) ) ) )
```

Comment: Indent the output nicely and it is of more use.

Comment: @hakre tidied id up a bit but to be honest I find it very confusing and am not sure I've improved it much :/

Comment: @MeltingDoc: I edited it a bit, see the changes. Just indent based on pairing with the arrays. You then can better read it and you might then directly spot the information you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

read this - http://www.shawnwilkerson.com/modx-revolution/2012/03/10/programmatically-working-with-the-moduser-object/ sample of code that you need:

```
/*
* modUser Groups
*/
$arry = print_r($user->getUserGroups(), true);
$modx->toPlaceHolder('user.groups', $arry);
```